# Add relationship backref order_by with alembic

Tags: flask, sqlalchemy, alembic, flask-migrate

I recently added Alembic to my Flask project and now my SQLAlchemy relationship sorting with order_by is no longer working. I believe this is because the migration file that is run is not picking up the order_by argument and I'm not sure how to get it in.

My model looks something like...

```
class Project(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'project'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)


class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    project_id = db.Column(db.ForeignKey(Project.id, ondelete="cascade"), index=True, nullable=False)
    project = db.relationship(Project, backref='members', order_by="User.id.desc()")
```

In the Alembic migration, I see the following...

```
    ...

op.create_table('user',
    sa.Column('id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    sa.Column('project_id', sa.Integer(), nullable=False),
    ...
    sa.ForeignKeyConstraint(['project_id'], ['project.id'], ondelete='cascade'),
)
op.create_index(op.f('ix_user_project_id'), 'user', ['project_id'], unique=False)

...
```

Looking at the migration, I'm not quite sure how SQLAlchemy is actually handling the relationship since I don't see any sort of backref mentioned anywhere, I guess SQLAlchemy just runs a query to get a project's users.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The migration file is correct, at DB level there is no *backref*, there is just the created foreign key linking the users entities with the projects.
In fact, as you said, sqlalchemy will issue a new query the first time you access a user's `user.project` attribute, joining on the *project_id* field. Just as a side note, if you want to join the projects' columns altogether while querying users, you should use the [joinedload option](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/loading_relationships.html)

Regarding the "order_by" used in the relationship declaration, it is only applied to the loaded relationship, such as in this example from the official docs:

```
class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parent'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child", order_by="Child.id")
```

In the example above, when accessing `parent.children`, the results will be ordered by the children's IDs.

In your case this does not make sense because it's a many to one relationship, and for each user you only have one project. Maybe you should move it to the project model:

```
class Project(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'project'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer(), primary_key=True)
    members = db.relationship('User', backref='project', order_by='User.id.desc()')
```

This way, whenever you access a project's `project.members` attribute you will get a sorted list of users.